# Access violation calling memcpy() inside JNI library doing USB i/o

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I am writing a Java application that executes USB I/O on Windows 10 with Java 10 JDK.  My i/o library is the libusb api.  The app loads a JNI library .dll compiled/built in Visual Studio 2017 with both Microsoft Visual 2013 C++ and Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 installed.  This application generates the following crash warning when ran inside a Netbeans 11.1 project.

> EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000002e1bbcd122e, pid=444, tid=3244
>   JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (10.0+46) (build 10+46)
>   Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (10+46, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
>
> Problematic frame:
>   C  [VCRUNTIME140D.dll+0x122e]

The problem function is my USB read function within the C code in the VisualStudio-built .dll.

JNI.c

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_SWMAPI_IoUSB_read
(JNIEnv * env, jobject thisObj, jbyteArray jArr, jint size, jlong javaHandle){   

    //Convert jLong to device handle pointer
    libusb_device_handle * handle = (libusb_device_handle * )javaHandle;

    //jbyteArray jArr: byte [] buffer.  Must be overwritten with USB read data from device with 
    //                                  corresponding handle javaHandle.
    //jlong javaHandle:  long passed from java representing the device to I/O.
    //jint size:         jArr length (e.g. buffer.length), used for debugging.

    int status;         //return code value
    int bytes_written;
    int bytes_read;

    MESSAGE Message;    //C struct containing 9 bytes of message header and (n) bytes of payload.

    int length = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, jArr);

    jbyte * bufferIn = (*env)->GetPrimitiveArrayCritical(env, jArr, NULL);  //get memory from jArr

    //copy data in bufferIn to a Message struct.
    memcpy((unsigned char *)&Message, (unsigned char *)bufferIn, length);  

    //write the Message out to device
    bytes_written = libusb_control_transfer(handle, CTRL_OUT, MEM_RQ, 0, 0, (unsigned char *)&Message, length, 0);

    if(bytes_written == length){
        //read data in from Device to &Message
        bytes_read = libusb_control_transfer(handle, CTRL_IN, MEM_RQ, 0, 0, (unsigned char 
        *)&Message, sizeof(MESSAGE), 30000);

        status = (bytes_written < 0) ? bytes_read :                 // I/O Error
            (bytes_written < length) ? USB_STATUS_SHORT_WRITE :     // Check for short write
            LIBUSB_SUCCESS;
        if(Message.payload.length >= 0){                            //If read data > 0
            printf("Attempting memcpy\n");
            fflush(stdout);

            // The error appears on the line below
            memcpy((unsigned char *)bufferIn,(unsigned char *)&Message, MAX_HEADER_LENGTH + 
            Message.payload.length);

            printf("Success memcpy\n");
            fflush(stdout);
        }
    }

    (*env)->ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical(env, jArr, bufferIn, 0);
    return status;
}
```

This function has been working for my project up until today.  Its frequency is approx 1 out of 3 runs.  Can anyone please advise me on how I can move forward to solving this issue?

Comment: Is it safe to say memcpy is a banned function on a Windows machine?

Comment: Why would you ask if `memcpy()` is a "banned function"?  And where does 'length` come from?  The function is passed `jint size`, not `length`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I was just wondering if Windows would try to control certain function that would be deemed too unsafe.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/memcpy-wmemcpy?view=vs-2019.  I forgot the code for length.  It is there now.

Comment: Obvious question time: what is `sizeof(MESSAGE)`, what is `length`, and what is `MAX_HEADER_LENGTH + Message.payload.length`? Also, did you verify that `bufferIn` is not a null pointer? Also, is the payload fully contained within `MESSAGE` or does it come after, because you only read `sizeof(MESSAGE)` bytes from USB into `Message` but try to `memcpy` more out of it.

Comment: @idioteque90 Microsoft is lying to you when they claim functions like `memcpy()` and `strcpy()` are "deprecated".  They're only "deprecated" by Microsoft, and a cynic would say that's to "help" the writing of Microsoft-specific code to make porting to another platform harder.  See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm  "As a result of the numerous deviations from the specification the Microsoft implementation cannot be considered conforming or portable."

Comment: @Botje I have checks in my source code for bufferIn and the return values from the control transfers.  I removed some lines in hopes of making my code above more readable.  sizeof(MESSAGE) is always 309 bytes (header + 300 bytes max for the payload).  Subsequently my values for bytes_read is always 309.

Comment: And is the passed-in `byte[]` from Java at least 309 bytes large?

Comment: It would be variable.

Comment: That might be a problem: you can only write into the allocated space. If you passed in a `byte[]` of length 12 and try to write back a response of length 230, that will crash. Try allocating a new `byte[]` from JNI instead overwriting `bufferIn`.